# Xcode 8.1 UI Testing twoFingerTap() fails on Google Maps view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, gmsmapview

Since upgrading to Xcode 8.1 my UI tests that use `twoFingerTap()` to zoom out on a Google Maps `GMSMapView` have been failing with

> Assertion Failure: Element.swift:135: UI Testing Failure - Unable to find unoccluded area to perform event.

The message preceding that is

> Recompute visible frame by excluding frames of occluding elements StatusBar and "*the view's identifier*"

Anyone have any idea what I should do about that? Tried `tapWithNumberOfTaps(1, numberOfTouches: 2)` and same thing happens.

**NB.** The problem is definitely with multi-finger taps only -- `doubleTap()` and `pinchWithScale(2.0, velocity: 1.0)` continue to work fine under Xcode 8.1. `pinchWithScale(0.5, velocity: -1.0)` continues to move origin instead of zooming, which is what it did to `GMSMapView` in Xcode 7 as well.

Comment: Same problem here (Xcode 8.2 beta (8C30a), Swift 3.0.2) , have you managed to find a workaround ?

It appears to fail more often on 4" devices simulators such as iPhone 5 or SE. I have far less problems on larger devices...

Comment: Closest I could come was digging into the subviews by index and tapping them manually. That works ... occasionally. At the moment all our Google Maps tests still disabled and back on the manual list :(

Comment: Ok thanks, hoping for a more robust solution 

Comment: @alexcurylo Did you found solution for your problem?

Comment: @Ramis What I ended up doing was creating a 'Zoom' button when UI Testing and tapping that

Comment: @alexcurylo For as it is not working, but for for other as shown [here](https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/Map) it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you're drawing your UI, or using storyboards. Nevertheless, it doesn't appear that you have the elements drawn to the view properly. Perhaps using constraints you can secure the element to your view.

Comment: Use `self.googleMapView = [[GMSMapView alloc] init];` and set its `accessibilityIdentifier` and `addSubview` directly to container. Works fine when run from Xcode 7. So not seeing how constraints would help here.

Comment: @alexcurylo - i'm adding google map view as a subview in my application and setting it's accessibilityIdentifier still it's not accessible.i want to write UITest for Map view existence and tap on particular marker.i tried with finding view hierarchy from app.debugdescription but cannot find map view in it.Any help,How to achieve?

Comment: The hierarchy is different every time you run and there appears to be no way to identify a particular marker reliably that I've found yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ive just upgraded to Xcode9 (beta) and this issue appears to be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already solve your case but It will help if you put Google Map inside another view and then set it's accessibility in storyboard (make sure Accessibility's "Enabled" and "User Interaction Enabled" is checked)

Then you can find it inside otherElements and tap or doubleFingerTap on it.